# Trying to Insert Values into a Database from TextBoxes

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am totally stumped on this one, and I'm brand new to C# so maybe one of you fine folks can help me out. I'm trying to update a database from form fields using ADO.NET.

Basically, the error I'm getting is that I am trying to insert null values into the database. The exact text of the error is:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects.
```

Here is the code behind for the page I am trying to use:

```
private void ExecuteInsert(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string city, string phone)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string sql = "INSERT INTO contactInfo (firstName, lastName, emailAddress, city, phone) VALUES "
                + " (@firstName, @lastName, @emailAddress, @city, @phone)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@emailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@phone", SqlDbType.Int, 10);

        param[0].Value = firstName;
        param[1].Value = lastName;
        param[2].Value = emailAddress;
        param[3].Value = city;
        param[4].Value = phone;

        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstName.Text != null)
    {
        //call the method to execute insert to the database
        ExecuteInsert(firstName.Text,
                      lastName.Text,
                      emailAddress.Text,
                      city.Text,
                      phone.Text);
        Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
        ClearControls(Page);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Please enter your name");
    }
}

public static void ClearControls(Control Parent)
{

    if (Parent is TextBox)
    { (Parent as TextBox).Text = string.Empty; }
    else
    {
        foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls)
            ClearControls(c);
    }
}
```

If there is another way that I should be doing this, I would love to hear it. I just can't seem to find good information online.

Comment: Why are you using an array in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];
```

Should be (array is too big and you don't set last parameter):

```
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];
```

Comment: +1, Basically, you're assigning `param[5]` into the collection, when `param[5]` is NULL.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, that's exactly the type of problem I've been running into over and over with this project. I can't see the forest for the trees because I'm so used to PHP. The code works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];`

to

`SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];`

You can add your parameters directly to `cmd.Parameters` without creating temp array.